# Sparse matrix multiplication in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, linear-algebra

I want to implement the following formula in pytorch in a batch manner:

```
x^T A x
```

where **x** has shape: [BATCH, DIM1]
and **A** has shape: [BATCH, DIM1, DIM1]

I managed to implement it for the dense matrix A as follows:

`torch.bmm(torch.bmm(x.unsqueeze(1), A), x.unsqueeze(2)).squeeze()`.

However, now I need to implement it for a SPARSE matrix **A** and I am failing to implement it.

The error that I am getting is `{RuntimeError}bmm_sparse: Tensor 'mat2' must be dense`, which comes from the `torch.bmm(x.unsqueeze(1), A)` part of the code.

In order to reproduce my work you could run this:

```
import torch
sparse = True # switch to dense to see the working version

batch_size = 10
dim1 = 5
x = torch.rand(batch_size, dim1)
A = torch.rand(batch_size, dim1, dim1)

if sparse:
   A = A.to_sparse_coo()
xTAx = torch.bmm(torch.bmm(x.unsqueeze(1), A), x.unsqueeze(2)).squeeze()
```

My pytorch version is `1.12.1+cu116`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as simple as changing the order of multiplications from
`(xT A) x` to `xT (Ax)`.